# User's facebook details not being received into hidden fields

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api, jquery-mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the facebook javascript sdk to get a logged in user's public data. What I want to do is bind the values to hidden field in the form and when submitted, get the values in a php file  which will insert into MySQL database. But when I submit the form, there are no values. Why is that? If I need to provide more info, please let me know. When I login, I can see my facebook name and profile pic on the web app.

```
//Hidden fields within form

<input type="hidden" name="hdnFacebookId" id="hdnFacebookId" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="hdnUsername" id="hdnUsername" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="hdnFirstName" id="hdnFirstName" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="hdnLastName" id="hdnLastName" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="hdnFacebookImg" id="hdnFacebookImg" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="hdnFacebookUrl" id="hdnFacebookUrl" value="">
<br/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="setValues()" data-theme="b" value="Submit" class="ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false">

<script>
function updateUserInfo(response) {
 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
   document.getElementById('myFacebookImg').src = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + response.id + "/picture";
   document.getElementById('myFacebookName').innerHTML = response.name;

   function setValues(){
        document.postAJourneyForm.hdnFacebookId.value = response.id;
        document.postAJourneyForm.hdnUsername.value = response.username;
        document.postAJourneyForm.hdnFirstName.value = response.first_name;
        document.postAJourneyForm.hdnLastName.value = response.last_name;
        document.postAJourneyForm.hdnFacebookImg.value = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + response.id + "/picture";
        document.postAJourneyForm.hdnFacebookUrl.value = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.username;
        //document.forms["postAJourneyForm"].submit();
   }
 });
```

}

```
//php file that gets the data to post to database
//I check in the code if it is empty before I can execute the query
//but it is always empty
//get the facebook data
$hdnFacebookId = $_POST['hdnFacebookId'];
$hdnUsername = $_POST['hdnUsername'];
$hdnFirstName = $_POST['hdnFirstName'];
$hdnLastName = $_POST['hdnLastName'];
$hdnFacebookImg = $_POST['hdnFacebookImg'];
$hdnFacebookUrl = $_POST['hdnFacebookUrl'];


//Updated with JSON
<script>
function updateUserInfo(response) {
 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
   document.getElementById('myFacebookImg').src = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + response.id + "/picture";
   document.getElementById('myFacebookName').innerHTML = response.name;
   document.getElementById('facebookUrl').href = "https://www.facebook.com/" + response.username;

   var JSONObject = {
    "facebookId":response.id,
    "facebookName":response.username,
    "facebookFirstName":response.first_name,
    "facebookLastName":response.last_name
   };
   document.getElementById('hdnFacebookId').innerHTML = JSONObject.facebookId;
   document.getElementById('hdnUsername').innerHTML = JSONObject.facebookName;
   document.getElementById('hdnFirstName').innerHTML = JSONObject.facebookFirstName;
   document.getElementById('hdnLastName').innerHTML = JSONObject.facebookLastName;
   document.getElementById('hdnFacebookImg').innerHTML = JSONObject.facebookImage;
   document.getElementById('hdnFacebookUrl').innerHTML = JSONObject.facebookUrl;


 });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you really need that `setValues` function? Just let the fields be updated together with the name and the picture

Comment: I had tried without it and it did not work. I got a little desperate and tried that. When I'm logged in, I can see my profile pic and name within an img tag and div tag on another page on the app, but on the page with the form the data does not go into the hidden input fields and so nothing is posted

Comment: Heads up though man, it's against Facebook policies to use data pulled from Facebook, without repeating it in an input form, to store it in your own databases or manipulate it otherwise.  In other words, they regulate transparency where data handling is concerned.

Comment: So, I have to use an input form to view the data

Answer (score 1):

To set values.

```
$('#hdnFacebookId').val(response.id);
$('#hdnUsername').val(response.username);
$('#hdnFirstName').val(response.first_name);
$('#hdnLastName').val(response.last_name);
$('#hdnFacebookImg').val('https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture');
$('#hdnFacebookUrl').val('http://graph.facebook.com/' + response.username);
```

Comment: No good. When I login, I have the facebook data but when I navigate to the page with the form, the facebook data is not in the hidden input elements to be posted

Comment: @ColinRoe you want to post data or read data? Either way, why don't use JSON? Create a JSON data array using PHP and then inject it into your HTML code.

Comment: post. Before, I had tried doing an example based on the facebook developers documentation using the facebook-php-sdk (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/) and that didn't work either. Very frustrating. Have no knowledge of JSON, but I'll try it.

Comment: @ColinRoe JSON will make your life easier. It works for POST and GET.

Comment: I moved my project to a live server to test as opposed to the local server I was using. I am now able to receive an user's facebook data once they give permission and save to a database.